# Is there any way to see source functions in Python 3 Modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm fairly new to the language and am wondering if it's possible to see the functions that are being used in a certain Python 3 module?

Specifically the ones in the "ipaddress" module, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by *see the functions that are being used*?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html

Generally, this type of information can be found in the languages docs.

---

As mentioned by John in the comments, implementations can be found here:

http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/ipaddress.py

Comment: I think OP wants to see the implementation source code, which is linked from the top of the docs page you posted.  Specifically here: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/ipaddress.py

Comment: Also, sometimes `inspect.getsource` can be helpful :-).

Comment: You should consider adding the relevant parts of those links _directly_ in your answer, @tehp.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to getting the source code online, if you have a standard Python install it should be already sitting in an easily found location on your hard-drive. In my case it is found as a file in `C:\Python34\Lib`. Needless to say, if you go this route you need to be careful to not modify (or, even worse, delete) the file.